# Best way to execute custom logic when setting value to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata

What is the most recommended approach to execute custom logic when setting value of `MutableLiveData`?

I have a `ViewModel` with several properties `isConnecting` and `isConnected`.
I want to set `isConnecting` to `false` when `isConected` is changed

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _isConnecting = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isConnecting: LiveData<Boolean>
        get () = _isConnecting
    
    private var _isConnected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isConnected: LiveData<Boolean>
        get () = _isConnected
}
```

One way to do it is creating a function inside `MyViewModel` and set both properties:

```
fun setConnected(value: Boolean) {
    _isConnected.value = value
    _isConnecting.value = false
}
```

This is okay, but one must never set `_isConnected` manually and always use function `setConnected()`. It can not be guaranteed and thus there may be bugs.

Another way to do it is to make `MyViewModel` observe its own `MutableLiveData`:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // ...

    private val isConnectedObserver = Observer<Boolean> {
        _isConnecting.value = false
    }

    init {
        isConnected.observeForever(isConnectedObserver)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        isConnected.removeObserver(isConnectedObserver)
    }
}
```

This avoids problem of first approach, but is just awful.

But is there a better way? For example using setters somehow?

Comment: but this two examples are doing different things in first both properties are independent(so we can have state false and false as fx is not connecting and not connected but we have an error) in second,  once `isConnected` CHANGED(not set to true) _isConnecting is false (so it would not work fx when reconnectiog) ... also "best way" always smells "opinion-based"

Comment: also you have `Transformations.map` if connecting is simple !connected you can do (in java) `_isConnecting = Transformations.map(_isConnected, b->!b);`

Comment: @Selvin I've edited my code so both approaches set `_isConnecting` to `false` when `isConnected` is changed

Comment: `_isConnected` is private so you only need to worry about avoiding setting it manually inside this class. If you can't trust yourself not to do that, then you would need to encapsulate `_isConnected` and `_isConnecting` together into a wrapper class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but what if class grows (for example adding `isLoading`, `isLoaded`, `isOnline`)? All these new properties also need to be set to `false` when `isConnected` changed

Comment: Sounds like you need a state machine. Make an enum of all the possible states, and then you only need one LiveData to track the state.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thank you, your suggestion will be helpful for me. I will introduce some state enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MediatorLiveData` to observe other `LiveData` objects and react on onChanged events from them:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _isConnecting = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().also { liveData ->
        liveData.addSource(_isConnected) { connected ->
            // isConnected changed, some logic here
            if (connected) {
                liveData.value = false
            }
        }
    }
    val isConnecting: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isConnecting

    private var _isConnected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isConnected: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isConnected
}
```

Comment: This seems as a good solution, but what if class grows? Adding `isLoading`, `isLoaded`, `isOnline` properties that also needs to be all set to `false` when `isConnected` changes. All of these new properties also need to be of type `MediatorLiveData` and it just adds a lot of code. Is there a way to set all those properties to `false` in `_isConnected` setter? or maybe a way to shorten current code? I'm new to Kotlin

Comment: I think this answers my main question. I think it is possible to create separate mediator (as another class property) that listens to changes in isConnected and resets all other properties. Thanks